# How can I create a recursive function along maintaining the history of the local variables?

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion

Below is a function that basically takes a multi-dimensional array and converts it into a single-dimensional array. I am using recursion to solve this. Also, there is one constraint - I cannot use a global variable, so no variables can be defined outside of the function.

Here is the function.

```
function flattenArray(someArr) {
    var results = [];
    if(isArrayLike(someArr)) {
        for(var i = 0; i != someArr.length; i++) {
            flattenArray(someArr[i])
        }
    } else {
        results.push(someArr);
    }
    return results;
}
```

Here, the function will always return a blank array, since every time the function recurs, it clears the array. So, how can you avoid this without using a global variable?

Assume: isArrayLike() function returns true or false.

Comment: Well, basically you do nothing with returned value of that `flattenArray` call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the accumulator along:

```
function flattenArray(someArr, acc) {
  acc = acc || [];
  if (isArrayLike(someArr)) {
    for(var i = 0; i != someArr.length; i++) {
      flattenArray(someArr[i], acc)
    }
  } else {
    acc.push(someArr);
  }
  return acc;
}
```

Or without loops, using `reduce` and the builtin `Array.isArray`:

```
function flatten(xs) {
  return xs.reduce(function(acc, x) {
    return acc.concat(Array.isArray(x) ? flatten(x) : x)
  },[])
}
```

Answer (score 1):

why not try passing a array as second argument to function , initially blank array ie
 flattenArray(someArr,result) and than passing updated and latest result array every time you recurse